# How to bind a command defined in viewmodel of a child to an element in base window in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Consider the code snippet below for a second:

```
<StackPanel>
   <local:ChildElementWithCommand x:Name="ChildElementWithCommand">
   <Button Content="Test"> // Bind this button to a command from ChildElementWithCommand
</StackPanel>
```

How to bind this Button to a command from the usercontrol named ChildElementWithCommand (I am pretty sure that this is not a particularly clean architecture)

**ChildElementWithCommand.xaml.cs**

```
namespace Test
{
  public partial class ChildElementWithCommand : UserControl
  {
    public ViewModel vm;
    public ICommand MyCommand;
    public ChildElementWithCommand()
    {
      InitializeComponent();
      vm = new vm();
      MyCommand = vm.MyCommand; // I would like to use this command in Button above
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: @Clemens What do you mean by "private" view-model? And also when you wrote _"Controls with private view model do not work well with data binding to a parent DataContext or with DataTemplates in general."_?

Comment: Please post the **exact definition** of your `Command` property - is it in `ChildElementWithCommand` or in the _current_ `DataContext`'s ViewModel? Or somewhere else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This way

```xml
<StackPanel>
   <local:ChildElementWithCommand x:Name="ChildElementWithCommand">
   <Button Content="Test" Command="{Binding ElementName=ChildElementWithCommand, Path=SomeCommand}">
</StackPanel>
```

'`Path=`' is optional.

Comment: Does not seem to work, at least, in my case

Comment: @Quizcoder If your Command is defined in `ChildElementWithCommand` class (as you have stated in the question) and the command is defined like a `public ICommand SomeCommand { set; get; }` then the binding is correct..